# ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH when loading audio

Tags: html, audio

I've been trying to get background music working for my browser-based game. It's working great, but in Chrome I frequently have the music cut short and this error appears:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

I watched the Network tab and saw the audio file being loaded as it should be, with the 206 Partial Content status, until it hit that error and just stopped.

Reloading the page will usually yield the same result, but at a different point in the track. I have yet to encounter this problem in IE, it seems to only be Chrome that's affected.

Any suggestions as to what may be happening?

---

Example request/response:

```
GET /music/___________.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: ____________.net
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://____________.net/
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: SID=XXXXXXXXXX
Range: bytes=0-

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Tue, 26 Aug 2014 13:53:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4
Last-Modified: Fri, 13 Jun 2014 21:00:31 GMT
ETag: "219f1a-8ed344-4fbbdf7c339c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 9360196
Content-Range: bytes 0-9360195/9360196
Connection: close
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

Comment: Last I saw that error I believe it had something to do with gzip compression. But, as the error message alludes to, it happens when the file is bigger or smaller than the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen When you saw the error, was the solution to turn gzip on or off?

Comment: Well, most audio files are already compressed. It would not make much sense compressing it again. But you should confirm that compression is the problem before doing anything. Is `Content-Encoding:` among the response headers? If so, what is it set to?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VJjuWb1W is a paste of the request/response, as this is still happening.

Comment: How are you playing the audio?

Comment: @taco `document.createElement('audio')`, set some attributes including `.src`, then `.play()`.

Comment: Just for reseatch: What happens if you set "Accept-Ranges none" in the httpd.conf file. You will receive the entire file with a 200 OK response. Spite of overload, the error persists?

Comment: @mrneverdies Error does indeed persist. I got a 200 OK response, and no `Content-Range` response header, but after... ah, I just re-enabled ranges and it seems that the error happens consistently at 2.0 minutes after the request starts. I seem to be hitting some kind of timeout on the file being sent... Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle please ?

Comment: Could it have to do with mod_bwlimited? Maybe it has a limit on the bandwidth you can consume within 2 minutes per IP address, and it cuts you off or throttles afterwards. (Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any documentation for this module at all.) Can you try disabling mod_bwlimited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increasing Apache's `timeout` setting fixed it.

Basically Chrome was being "too clever" by only downloading fast enough to keep just ahead of the buffer, and Apache was getting bored.

Comment: I don't send background music to mobile devices - many don't support it anyway, but also data costs money. Sending a 10MB file every time is an *even worse* idea in the context of mobile browsers. ... Sometimes I pity the people who don't have the same unlimited data plan that I do, heh...

Answer (score 1):

*I was also facing this problem and the accepted solution didnət work for me. So, I leave my solution here for those who are also facing the error because this question comes up as the first result of the search.*

I was running an Nginx server and was facing this error.

First, open `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
gzip on;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

Then open your server configuration file, for me `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

```
...
server {
    ...
    server_name  example.com;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    ...
    location / {
         ...
         proxy_buffer_size 128k;
         proxy_buffers 4 256k;
         proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
         ...
   }
   ...
}
```

*If it doesn't work, try increasing the buffer size.*